# create constants from database values - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my app is developed in codeigniter.
i have table called user types in my db.

id | type
1  | admin
2  | student
3  | teacher

i am comparing the id value in several places in my code:

```
<?php
if($id == 1) { do something.. } 
else if($id == 2) { do something. }
?>
```

Instead of using magic numbers, i was thinking of putting the values in a config 
file like so:

```
$config['admin'] = 1;
$config['student'] = 2;
```

However, if later on some other developer adds a new type / changes
a type value in the db, then they will have to make the change in two places.
So is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using sessions?

Answer (score 0):

To make your data more persist, i would say use `redis`.

After that store values in redis(instead of session) like,

```
$this->redis->set($key, $val);
```

Example

```
$this->redis->set("user_type",1);// set this at login.
```

To retrieve value from redis,

```
$this->redis->get("user_type");
```

For this all you have to do is get, redis library file and redis config file(Avaliabe in CI 3)